# very large tables indexes

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-tuning

I have 2 large tables( millions of rows)  having similar columns ( one staging , one master) querying on all most all columns .

all columns are VARCHAR(200)

```
MERGE
INTO    [dbo].[TABLE1] [t1]
USING   [dbo].[TABLE2] [t2]
ON      [t1].[COL1] = [t2].[COL1]
        AND [t1].[COL2] = [t2].[COL2]
        AND [t1].[COL3] = [t2].[COL3]
        AND [t1].[COL4] = [t2].[COL4]
```

What is the correct index strategy.
Covering index wont work , as they are mostly used in predicates , rather than in Select .
Clustered index can be identity , which is not used at all. Then Nonclustered index having 4 columns will be too large .. 800 bytes.

Comment: I might suggest that you make a computed column that is a hash of the column values and then use this for an index.

Comment: Most frequently the indexes will be used for inserting and updating . Using Computing index on some hashes, will complicate

Comment: . . You have specified that you cannot create an index on all the columns needed by the comparison.  Hence, an index on a hashed value would be better than no index at all.